# Signal handlers and atexit of coverage.py for sub-process

Tags: python, signals, code-coverage

> To successfully write a coverage data file, the Python sub-process
>   under analysis must shut down cleanly and have a chance for
>   coverage.py to run the atexit handler it registers.
>
> For example if you send SIGTERM to end the sub-process, but your
>   sub-process has never registered any SIGTERM handler, then a coverage
>   file won’t be written. See the atexit docs for details of when the
>   handler isn’t run.

The above [document](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1/subprocess.html#signal-handlers-and-atexit) seems to say that I need to give a handler for `SIGTERM` if I kill a sub-process with the `SIGTERM` signal so that `coverage.py` could run `atexit` handler it registers.

However, I am confused what should I put in the handler for `coverage.py` and not even sure if my understanding is right or not.

If my understanding is right, for example,

```
# Each sub-process should register the signal handler.
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    # What should I do in here for coverage.py?
    # Is it just enough to register the empty handler?
    pass

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
```

if not, what does the document mean?

Answer (score 0):

With an empty signal handler, as defined in the question, the program will now ignore SIGTERM, which is great for coverage.py, but now your program won't exit after receiving a TERM signal. Your handler needs to somehow communicate with your process' main thread to tell it to stop whatever it's doing, both quickly and gracefully.

If your program uses threads, it may have to reach out to each of those threads and similarly communicate to them that it's time to stop what they're doing. You'll want to try to keep any of that complexity out of your signal handler, because it shouldn't have to know what the rest of your program is doing, but either way, sending SIGTERM to your program should cause it to gracefully shut down, and that's on the program to implement, not coverage.py, and not the operating system you're running on.

This answer is probably a little late for the original poster, but I hope someone else will find it useful.